# Remove tuple from array of tuples

Tags: arrays, swift, tuples

Func to see if two arrays have some same values:

```
func hasAllSame(largeCombinedArry:[Int], wantToKeep: [Int])->Bool{
   var howManySame = [Int]()
   for intElement in largeCombinedArry{
      if wantToKeep.contains(intElement){
         howManySame.append(intElement)
      }
   }
   howManySame.sort()
   if wantToKeep == howManySame{
      print("These are the same!")
      return true
   }
   else{
      print("These are NOT same!")
      return false
   }
}
```

Array of tuples declared like this:

```
var TuplesArry:[(score: Double, value: [Int])] = []
```

Array filled thusly:

```
for (arry1, score) in zip(arryOfArrays, AllScores) {
   let calculatedDiff = otherValue - score
   TuplesArry.append((score: calculatedDiff, value: arry1))
}

var arrayForComparison = [8,9,7,6]
arrayForComparison.sort()
```

Error occurs here after several iteration at function call hasAllSame()

```
for i in 0..<TuplesArry.count{
   if hasAllSame(largeCombinedArry: TuplesArry[i].value, wantToKeep:                                                                  
   arrayForComparison){
      //do nothing           
   }
   else{
      /*
       want to remove tuple that does not have all elements that are
       in arrayForComparison
       */
      TuplesArry.remove(at: i)                    
   }
}
```

This code seems to be working but it seems like tuplesArry.count continues to decrease and iterator i continues to increase until error occurs "fatal index out of range"

My goal is to remove a tuple from the array of tuples if it's value does not meet criteria.

I've also tried something like:

```
for tuple in TuplesArry{
   if hasAllSame(largeCombinedArry: tuple.value, wantToKeep:   
   arrayForComparison){
            //do nothing
   }
   else{
      //this does NOT work
      let index = TuplesArry.index(of:tuple)
      TuplesArry.remove(at: index)
   }
}
```

Comment: Please consider this note in the Language Guide: *Tuples are useful for temporary groups of related values. They’re not suited to the creation of complex data structures. If your data structure is likely to persist beyond a temporary scope, model it as a class or structure, rather than as a tuple.*

Comment: @vadian I took this into consideration and implemented it as class. Thank you for your feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate issue is that you need to iterate in reverse to avoid the "index out of range" issue.

The much simpler solution is to use `filter` on your array. Then you entire `for` loop can be replaced with:

```
TouplesArry = TouplesArry.filter { hasAllSame(largeCombinedArry: $0.value, wantToKeep: arrayForComparison) }
```